# Visual Studio 2015 No C++ CLR Templates

Tags: c++, winforms, templates, visual-studio-2015, clr

I've been programming in android and have recently moved on to Visual C++ so I can make Computer Programs (Rather than apps), But when I create a C++/CLR emtpy Project in visual studio 2015, everything is fine at first but when I go to add a windows form, there are simply no templates, whatsoever. The 'installed' tab doesn't have ANYTHING under it, so thus I can't make a form to make my program. I have looked at other solutions but  it seems, there is nothing for visual studio 2015, nothing else seems to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: May be you have to add "a reference" to some .NET library? I ain't a .NET specialist, but I know that .NET projects use references to libraries.

Comment: I Thought that might be the case. But I figured if all the other file formats had templates then maybe it was just an error.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Changes in Visual Studio 2015 Affecting C++ Developers - This ensures that non-C++ developers don’t have to pay the setup time and disk-space price for installing C++ bits that they don’t need. At the same time, C++ developers can still get the pieces they need.

source: [entry about clr templates missing in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/)